# Sql server when rebuild index table hard disk size 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I've got a major problem

I tried to rebuild index a table with 300M records
I've had 100GB Free storage

when the process was ongoing free space has gone to 0 and the rebuild stucked

Now I can't access any data on this specific table
(the sql log file size seems as the table was before)

Anyone has a suggestion what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: if it is not a live production database, then I would unmount the database and mount it again - possible after a database server/service restart. By unmounting I mean taking the database offline and then detach/remove it - just to add it again and take it online.

Comment: Tried to... taking hours to shut it down... and unfortunatlly it is production

Comment: Will bring up backup from 2 days ago... my last option Thanks

Comment: Seems you should consider to use partitioning. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've shrink the database logile and from almost 700GB it shrinked to nothing.

somehow the table had data again probably it resumed the reindexing after doing that.

Back to normal